# Case When or iif syntax expression in jooq

Tags: java, mysql, jooq

I am trying to reproduce this MySQL query in jooq.

messageTable1, messageTable2 same column

```
select 
msg.index as index,
left(msg.message, if(msg.type = 1, 10, msg.maxLength)) as message
from
messageTable1 as msg

select 
msg.index as index,
left(msg.message, if(msg.type = 1, 10, msg.maxLength)) as message
from
messageTable2 as msg
```

making function java

```
public Message getMessageTest(String tableName) {
    return roDslContext.select(
           DSL.field("msg.index").as("index"),
           left(DSL.field( "{0}", String.class, "msg.message"), 
              when(DSL.field("msg.type").eq(1), 10, DSL.field( "{0}", String.class, "msg.maxLength").as("message)
           .from(tableName)
           .fetchOneInto(Message.class);
}
```

but....

```
when(DSL.field("msg.type").eq(1), 10, DSL.field( "{0}", String.class, "msg.maxLength").as("message)
```

jooq is field  msg.maxLength ... not accept

also so iif

how case, when, iif insert field column data??

Comment: tableName -> "messageTable1" or "messageTable2"

Answer (score 0):

#### Using the [code generator](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/)

I'm assuming you're not using the code generator in this example, because you want to make your column references dynamic, depending on the table name.

There's a possibility of generating common interfaces onto your tables, which would abstract over the two table types. Also, there are `Table.rename(String)` methods generated on those tables, which allow for renaming a table `MESSAGE_TABLE_1.rename("message_table_2")`. So your query would look like this:

```java
public Message getMessageTest(String tableName) {
    MessageTable1 msg = MESSAGE_TABLE_1.rename(tableName);

    return roDslContext
        .select(
            msg.INDEX,
            left(msg.MESSAGE, if_(msg.TYPE.eq(1), val(10), msg.MAX_LENGTH))
        )
        .from(msg)
        .fetchOneInto(Message.class);
}
```

As always, this is assuming the following static import:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

#### The actual problem

You seem to be attempting to construct field references using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/). You did it right for `msg.index` via `DSL.field("msg.index")`, but somehow tripped over the templating syntax for `msg.message`. This doesn't make sense:

```java
field("{0}", String.class, "msg.message");
```

When using a template, the placeholder `{0}` needs to be replaced by a `QueryPart` instance. You can't just pass a `String` instead (which would be interpreted as a bind value). What you meant to do here is any of these:

```java
// If you really need templating, though here, you don't:
field("{0}", String.class, name("msg", "message"));

// Instead, just do this, if you want quoted names:
field(name("msg", "message"), String.class);

// Or this, if you don't care about quoting the name
field("msg.message", String.class);
```